# Is it possible to associate a node to a workflow in alfresco?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I have to achieve the following:
Once a calendar event is created, start a workflow in which the assigned users (submitted with the form) are added to the workflow. 
What I'm thinking to do is: 
1 - to store the properties required for workflow in an aspect attached to the calendar then, 
2 - to start the workflow from an addAspect behaviour and (associate it with the calendar event)
3 - then in an association behaviour add person(s) to the workflow as they're associated with the workflow.

I'm thinking this requires me to associate calendar-event => workflow in a source => target relationship so that as people are added, they're subscribed to the same behaviour policies.

Comment: How would this be different from something like a Review and Approve workflow, where a particular document is associated with started workflow instance?

Comment: @Gagravarr I haven't played with the ootb workflows yet. But in this case there's no document associated with this workflow and users can be added to the workflow instance after it is started.

Comment: Try with the OOB workflows, check with nodebrowser etc, then let us know if that's roughly what you want (just added later) or not!

Comment: I am already doing this. Just a qq, can a workflow be started without assignees? I haven't seen anything to indicate otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any nodeRef in de bpm_package. OOTB it's for example not possible to start a workflow on a folder. So starting the workflow from a JavaScript action you can do anything, like execute it on a calendar item (which is a node).

Create a calendar item and you'll see that via the Repository browser under the site/calendar a new .ics file has been created which is your node.